# Where can I leave luggage in Frankfurt, either airport or train station?

Tags: luggage-storage, train-stations, fra, frankfurt

I need to find a place to leave my luggage in lockers for 2 days in Frankfurt, either the airport (Terminal 1) or at the train station. I have to go by train to Stuttgart for 2 days without luggage. The luggage is 5 bags, 28 inches.

Comment: Please clarify: it is 5 pieces of luggage, each measure 28 inches? I did edit the question, but left that as you stated it.

Answer (score 7):

There are lockers at Frankfurt Main Station (Frankfurt Hbf). You can leave your bags there. A small locker costs 3 or 4 Eur per day, a big locker costs 5 or 6 Eur per day. Note, that day ends at midnight, it doesn't matter when you put your bags in the locker - at 3:00 or at 23:00.

[image: Lockers at Frankfurt Hbf]
([full picture](http://www.bahnhof.de/contentblob/11946266/Frankfurt+%28Main%29+Hbf_locationBild/data.jpg))

You can also store your bag at the airport for up to three months. [Here is the information](https://poi.frankfurt-airport.com/en/service/gepaeckaufbewahrung) about locations, prices and working hours.

Comment: I recently had to store a bag at Frankfurt station and it took me a while to find a locker that was both functioning and unoccupied. Bring coins. +1

Comment: Munich HBF has a note-to-coin machine - I would expect Frankfurt to have the same?